# retrieve if a user has a special privilege using javascript ex: prvOverridePriceEngineQuote (not a role)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to know if a user has a special privilege "prvOverridePriceEngineQuote" but I don't get it done.

My code is looking like:

```
var userid = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
var userhasPrivilege;   

    var quoteFetchXML = "<fetch version=\"1.0\" output-format=\"xml-platform\" mapping=\"logical\" distinct=\"false\">" +
        "<entity name=\"privilege\">" +
            "<attribute name=\"name\" />" +
            "<filter>" +
                "<condition attribute=\"name\" operator=\"eq\" value=\"prvOverridePriceEngineQuote\" />" +
            "</filter>" +
            "<link-entity name=\"roleprivileges\" from=\"privilegeid\" to=\"privilegeid\">" +
                "<link-entity name=\"role\" from=\"roleid\" to=\"roleid\">" +
                    "<link-entity name=\"systemuserroles\" from=\"roleid\" to=\"roleid\">" +
                        "<link-entity name=\"systemuser\" from=\"systemuserid\" to=\"systemuserid\">" +
                            "<filter>" +
                                "<condition attribute=\"systemuserid\" operator=\"eq\" value=\"" + userid + "\" />" +
                            "</filter>" +
                        "</link-entity>" +
                    "</link-entity>" +
                "</link-entity>" +
            "</link-entity>" +
        "</entity>" +
    "</fetch>";

    var encodedFetchXML = encodeURIComponent(quoteFetchXML);

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/accounts?fetchXml=" + encodedFetchXML, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
```

It is working right when I test it in XRMToolBox but not when I run the code with javascript in Dynamics crm.

I get this error:

> "Could not find a property named 'privilegeid' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account'"
>
> "{\r\n  \"error\":{\r\n    \"code\":\"\",\"message\":\"Could not find a property named 'privilegeid' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account'.\",\"innererror\":{\r\n      \"message\":\"Could not find a property named 'privilegeid' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account'.\",\"type\":\"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException\",\"stacktrace\":\"   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectPathSegmentTokenBinder.ConvertNonTypeTokenToSegment(PathSegmentToken tokenIn, IEdmModel model, IEdmStructuredType edmType, ODataUriResolver resolver)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Visitors.SelectPropertyVisitor.ProcessTokenAsPath(NonSystemToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Visitors.SelectPropertyVisitor.Visit(NonSystemToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectBinder.Bind(SelectToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Bind(IEdmStructuredType elementType, IEdmNavigationSource navigationSource, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, IEdmStructuredType elementType, IEdmNavigationSource navigationSource)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpand()\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.GetEntitySet(String entitySetName)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong or how I could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused because you're executing the FetchXML on the Account entity instead of the Privilege one.

You need to change this line:

```
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/accounts?fetchXml="
```

By this other one:

```
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/privileges?fetchXml="
```